# XNA C# performance issue

Tags: c#, performance, windows-phone-7, xna

I'm drawing multiple circles (not filled) on the screen, I'm using the same sprite for all of them, but different scale values. Problem is, when there's about 6-10 of them, it lags a lot. Texture itself is 400x400 png picture. Note when using `spritebatch.Draw()` method with least amount of arguments, performance improves significantly. I'm drawing when cycling through list which holds scale values. It may be important to mention, I'm developing for WP7 platform and lag occurs only on slower devices.

Here's code I'm using:

```
for (int i = 0; i < active_triangles.Count; i++)
                {                        
                    spriteBatch.Draw(circle, circle_origin, null, Color.White, 0, circle_pivot, scales[i], SpriteEffects.None, 0);
                    active_triangles[i].Draw(spriteBatch);
                }
```

triangles' Draw method:

```
public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        spriteBatch.Draw(texture, position, frame, Color.White * alpha, rotation, pivot, 1, SpriteEffects.None, 0);
    }
```

Comment: Just a tip! Please read [faq] and [ask] a couple of times..

Comment: it would be quite helpful if you showed us the actual code you're using.

Comment: As Oren said, please post some more relevant code (especially the triangle's .Draw(spriteBatch).

Comment: where do you have your `SpriteBatch.Begin` and `SpriteBatch.End` calls?

Comment: It would be much easier to determine the cause of the lag if you ran a profiler. See which methods consume most resources and you'll have your answer.

Comment: Is it possible that the alpha blending is causing the slow down? Trying removing `* alpha` in your draw call and see if there is any improvement.